# Find the function F such that

Tags: calculus

Find the function $F$ such that $logF'(x)=2x+e^x$

I must essentially take the definite integral of the expression but couldn't move any pencil, any hints?

Comment: what kind of $\log$ is this?

Comment: Is this $\log {d\over dx}F(x)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
F'(x)=e^{x}\cdot e^{x+e^x}
$$ giving
$$
F(x)=e^{x+e^x}-e^{e^x}.
$$

Comment: Why is there no constant?

Comment: Yes, one may add a constant term.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: It looks correct, but how did you find $F(x)$ directly, from mind?

Comment: If one differentiates $e^{x+e^x}$ one gets $(1+e^x)\cdot e^{x+e^x}=e^{x+e^x}+e^{2x+e^x}$.